# python packages are not getting installed in the local system

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download this packages into my system but due to office network environment they are not allowing me to download it. So do we have any alternative packages or else any solution for this kind of issues ?

The following are the packages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
```

I'm expecting a solution where I can download or else install this package such that I don't get any security issues.

Comment: There's probably a reason why they're not allowing you to download them.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, your office network has a firewall that is preventing you from pip installing. I don't know much about this but a while ago I had a similar error and this 3 posts might help you:

- [Pip not working behind firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468550/pip-not-working-behind-firewall)
- [Unable to install PIP behind a corporate firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701322/unable-to-install-pip-behind-a-corporate-firewall)
- [pip install pandas failed because of environment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124820/pip-install-pandas-failed-because-of-environment-error)

As one of the answers to one post said, you could also try talking to support department, nevertheless, this is not the only option/ if you are able to momentarily use another wifi/use cellular internet to bypass the network's firewall.

Answer (score -1):

Use a proxy server: You can try using a proxy server to access the package repository. You can set up a proxy server on your local machine or use a public proxy server. Make sure to check with your network administrator before using a proxy server.

Use a package manager: You can use a package manager like Anaconda or Miniconda to manage your Python packages. These package managers provide an alternative to pip and can be installed locally without requiring administrative privileges.

Download packages manually: You can download the packages manually from the official websites and install them locally

Comment: There's no indication that OP would be allowed to download a package manager that would bypass whatever restriction they currently face. Every one of these solutions would involve discussing their legality with the network administrator, at which point you may as well discuss the actual packages you want directly.